# Use of Dublin Core references and isReferencedBy terms

Tags: rdf, semantics, owl, dublin-core

The Dublin Core vocabulary expresses two terms:

- [references](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-references)
- [isReferencedBy](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-isReferencedBy)

The two terms are *inverses* whereas:

```
if A references B, then B is referenced by A
```

In a graph is it then (fully or to a certain extent) **required** to always insert and express both terms?

```
<http://example.org/A> dcterms:references <http://example.org/B>
<http://example.org/B> dcterms:isReferencedBy <http://example.org/A>
```

If it is not required, on behalf of what considerations should be both used, or just one of the two?

Answer (score 1):

*The original question said transitive, but should have said inverses.  The question has been corrected.  The relevant portion of the answer starts in the second paragraph.* The properties are not, as far as I can tell, transitive.  That a property *p* is transitive, means that for all *a*, *b*, *c*, if *p(a,b)* and *p(b,c)*, then *p(a,c)*.  I do not think it is necessarily the case that “if *a* references *b*, and *b* references *c*, then *a* references *c*.”  The relationship that you have described is that `references` and `isReferencedBy` are *inverses*.  A property *p* is the inverse of a property *q* if, for all *a* and *b*, *p(a,b)* if and only if *q(b,a)*.

The names of the properties do clearly suggest that they are inverses of each other, though I have not found an authoritative reference stating that.  Typically, data sources will only state the relationship in one direction.  Some kind of reasoner (and this might just be some application logic—it does not need to be a full-fledged RDFS or OWL reasoner) should be responsible for making the connection between the two properties.  For instance, if you are writing an application to build the graph of references, your application should look for triples using either property, and use that data as appropriate.

In RDF, it is typically easy to state either of the triples that would express the relationship “a references b”—you could either assert `a references b` or `b isReferencedBy a`.  However, in some formats, you will not have as much flexibility.  For instance, if you are using HTML `META` tags to describe an HTML document, the subject of the triple is fixed, so you'll need `references` to enumerate things that the document references, and `isReferencedBy` to enumerate things that reference the document.  If you are working in pure RDF and can write arbitrary triples, though, you really only need one property, although it still might be clearer and more concise in some circumstances to use both. For instance, it might be considered clearer to write:

```
A references B ;
  isReferencedBy C, D .
```

instead of

```
A references B .
C references A .
D references A .
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I have edited my question, replacing transitive with inverses. I believe the definition for both terms clearly states that one is the inverse of the other ('A related resource that is referenced, cited, or otherwise pointed to by the described resource.' and 'A related resource that references, cites, or otherwise points to the described resource.'): 'that is referenced' - 'that references'.

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli Yes, the textual description very strongly suggests that they should be inverses.  I meant that I couldn't find anything in the description of either property that actually stated, e.g., “`a references b` if and only if `b isReferencedBy a`,” as might be expected in a vocabulary description.

Comment: Although initially I thought it was irrelevant, actually DC is not an OWL, therefore a reasoning would require a 'manual' intervention to state the correlation between the two properties. What I am thinking here therefore, given that a 'maintainer' is defining both A and B, is that this decision is purely subjective, i.e. it's up to the 'maintainer' to choose whether to use one term on one subject, or both on both subjects. Hence when consuming 3rd party graphs I would look for one term and the other. Do we actually know how these two terms have been used in practical examples?

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli Right, the DC vocabulary is not defined as an OWL ontology, but it is available as RDFS.  You could still use a rules-based reasoner on it to infer, e.g., the closure of the `references` and `isReferencedBy` with the assumption that they are inverses.  I do not know whether one of these properties is used more often than the other, though I expect that it is often easier to annotate a document with a list of the things that it references (since that information is contained in the document) than to annotate it with the things by which it is referenced.